# go-hook to read user input from specific device

Tags: windows, go, winapi, keyboard, hid

While going through programs that can intercept keyboard/HID scanners in golang, I came across the [go-hook](https://github.com/moutend/go-hook) link and it is able to intercept all keyboard inputs but unable to determine the actual keyboard from which it was intercepted. If there is a way to know the device, then that would be really helpful as it will allow us to intercept the scanner and leave the actual keyboard input alone.

Comment: This is not supported in Windows. You can use [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) which allows you to identify the device, but doesn't allow you to intercept the input. Or you could install a [low-level keyboard hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)) which allows you to intercept input, but won't allow you to identify the input device.

Comment: Anyone aware of a library that is available where rawinput has been used to capture the keyboard input along with the source.